# How to install open-source python toolkit from the tar.gz file without using pip install in terminal?

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

I have the latest source code in tar.gz format for an open-source python toolkit and want to install it in terminal. How do I do that?

I have just downloaded the .gz file from the source code and need to install it. Unsure as to how to install it.

Comment: Use *pip*. Why would you not want to use *pip*? -- Also I am quite sure this question has been asked before, probably more than once. I recommend you search for it, there are probably good answers.

Comment: Thank you @sinorc. I cannot use pip as my work computer has network constraints which means trying to use pip install in terminal just leads to package errors. Hence was trying to see if I could install using the source code. Yes, I did see answers for this in the chats and tried it as well, but it's not working.

Comment: If you use the right combination of options, *pip* will not try to connect to the internet. Something like this: `python -m pip install --no-deps --no-index something.tar.gz`.

Comment: Thanks @sinoroc. Will try this and report back.